# How to set recyclerview minimum height wrap_content but maximum in percent using constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a recyclerview and i am using constraint layout . Now i want to use height as **wrap_content** but want to set maximum height in percent .How i can achieve this using constraint layout?

```
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_view"

    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_max="500dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Comment: What happens when the content is greater than the maximum height?

Comment: @FrancescoBocci then its working fine wrapping content

Comment: use guideline in constrain layout and change the unit to percentage and constrain recycler view to guideline

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `ConstraintLayout` you could use a `Guideline` as the following to constraint the `RecyclerView's` height.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline3" />
```

The `Guideline` has a `layout_constraintGuide_percent` in which you could specify the percentage you want for the `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try with This

```
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.17"
```